# spark application from kafka stream takes long time to produce recommendation

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, matrix-factorization

I am reading stream of data in my spark application from kafka stream. My requirement is to produce product recommendation for a user when he makes any request (search/browse etc.)

I already have a trained model containing score of users. I am using Java and org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel model to read the model once at start of my spark application. Whenever there is any browsing event, I call recommendProducts(user_id, num_of_recommended_products) API to produce recommendation for a user from my already existing trained model.

This API is taking ~3-5 seconds for generating result per user which is very slow and hence my stream processing lags behind. Are there any ways in which I can optimise the time of this API? I am considering increasing stream duration from 15 seconds to 1 minute as an optimisation (not sure of its results now)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `recommendProducts` in real time, doesn't make much sense. Since ALS model can make predictions only for users, which has been seen in the training dataset, it is better to `recommendProductsForUser` once, store the output in a store which supports first lookups by key and fetch results from there, when needed.

If adding storage layer is not an option, you can also take output of `recommendProductsForUser`, partition by id, checkpoint and cache predictions, and then `join` with input stream by id.